# Why email takes so long to load

Tags: database, performance, email

gmail and outlook take a good 3-4 seconds to load. This is very long from the standpoint of a high performance application.

My question is kind of directed towards db schema of emails - 
1. Is it that the server is doing aggregation instead of simple row lookup on the db (to find all email threads of a user), which takes so long? 
2. How can load time be minimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time (3-4 seconds) that you observe is not related to the database query. It is related to downloading all the required JavaScript libraries and building the user interface.

Comment: but amazon.com (or even stackoverflow.com) do not take so long. I dont see ui of gmail to be more complex than ui of amazon.com!

Comment: Turn on the dev console and monitor the trafic to see what is going on.